# Parse in javascript {{1,2},{3,4}},{{1.1,1.2},{1.0, 1.0}, {1.3,1.3}}

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have a string like {{1,2},{3,4}}, {{1.1,1.2},{1.0, 1.0}, {1.3,1.3}}
I need to get an array of arrays of pairs {number, number}.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to get a 2D-array?

Comment: Are you the one who is creating the string? Or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: 1) Yes, 2D array is suitable.
2) It comes from somewhere else.

I try to use regex. Expression /\{.*\}(\{.*\})*/ matches {{1,2},{3,4}},{{1.1,1.2} and {1.0, 1.0},{1.3,1.3}}

Answer (score 5):

Since the input almost looks like the array syntax, you can replace all curly braces with square braces to get a valid array:

```
var string = '{{1,2}, {2,3}}';
JSON.parse(string.replace(/}/g, ']').replace(/\{/g, '['));
// >>> [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

Note that I used [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the string.
If your input contains multiple `{..}`, separated by a comma, add additional braces: `'[' + .. + ']'`. Otherwise, you get something like `result = [1,2],[4,5];`, which does not offer the desired result.

Comment: I was *just* typing that. :-)

Comment: Thank you!That works. When I saw this string it seemed to me like JSON, but I haven't come to the idea with brackets replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it a variety of ways. You could replace the braces with square brackets, you can build a parser yourself that looks at every character and tracks whether you've opened or closed an array, or you could run multiple loops over the string, splitting it based on the patterns in it.

Eg. First loop - split on }},{{ as this only happens at the top level.

Second loop - split each on },{

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(JSON.parse("["+("{{1,2},{3,4}}, {{1.1,1.2},{1.0, 1.0}, {1.3,1.3}}"
    .replace(/{/g,'[').replace(/}/g,']'))+"]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just replace this { with this [ and this } with this ] and then parse it as a json